# Variable is null (only in Mozilla)

Tags: javascript, mozilla

Here is the resume of the code:

```
var client = new BinaryClient('ws://localhost:9001');
var context = null;
var store_data  = null;
//(.....)
if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
      navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true}, success, function(e) {
    alert('Error capturing audio.');
  });
} else alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.');

function success(e) {
      audioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
      context = new audioContext();
      audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(e);
      var bufferSize = 2048;
      store_data = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
      //(...)
}

//(....)
client.on('open', function() {
    console.log("createStream");
    Stream = client.createStream(command_list);
    var recording = false;

    window.startRecording = function() {
      document.getElementById("startbutton").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("stopbutton").disabled = false;

      recording = true;
      window.Stream.resume();
    }

    window.stopRecording = function() {
      document.getElementById("startbutton").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("stopbutton").disabled = true;

      recording = false
      //window.Stream.end();
      window.Stream.pause();
    }

    store_data.onaudioprocess = function(e){ //<---line of the error
        if(!recording) return;
        console.log ('recording');
        var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
        window.Stream.write(convertoFloat32ToInt16(left));
      }
//(..events generated from server..)
```

In chrome my code works just fine. In Mozilla I am getting always the error "store data is undefined". Any idea why? Because I am declaring `store_data` as global and when `getusermedia` is a `sucess` the value is changed.

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: Probably a [Race Condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Sounds like in Mozilla the BinaryClient opens before you call that `success` function. Where is that function being called from?

Comment: @Oriol I aleady edited and marked the place

Comment: @DanPrince Yes I think that is the problem. In Mozilla the `getusermedia` takes an eternity to fire up.

Comment: `navigator.getUserMedia` is deprecated and FF only kept `navigator.mozGetUserMedia` for backward compatibility. You should use the `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` API and its Promises system.

Comment: @Kaiido How can I put the audio on `mediastreamsource`?

Comment: to connect your stream to a scriptProcessor, you should do : 
`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
.then(
function(stream){
context = new AudioContext();
audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
var bufferSize = 2048;
store_data = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);

store_data.onaudioprocess = function(e){ //<---line of the error
if(!recording) return;
console.log ('recording');
var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
window.Stream.write(convertoFloat32ToInt16(left));
}

audioInput.connect(store_data);
}
)
.catch(
function(e){
console.log(e)
}
);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var client = new BinaryClient('ws://193.136.94.233:9001');
var context = null;
var gain = null;
var store_data  = null;
//(.....)

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true}) .then( function(stream){ 
context = new AudioContext(); 
audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream); 
var bufferSize = 4096; 
store_data = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
biquadFilter = context.createBiquadFilter();
biquadFilter.type = "lowpass";
biquadFilter.frequency.value = 11500;
biquadFilter.Q.value = 3;

ganho = context.createGain();
ganho.gain.value=0.5;

//audioInput.connect(ganho);//compresso
//ganho.connect(recorder);
//recorder.connect(context.destination); 

audioInput.connect(biquadFilter);
biquadFilter.connect(ganho);
ganho.connect(store_data);
store_data.connect(context.destination); 

store_data.onaudioprocess = function(e){
  if(!recording){
    //console.log("nada faz nada desta vida")
    return; 
 }
  console.log ('recording'); 
  var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0); 
  Stream.write(convertoFloat32ToInt16(left)); 
} 
  //audioInput.connect(store_data); 
} ) .catch( function(e){ console.log(e) } );

//(...)

client.on('open', function() {
    console.log("opened connection");


    //haveStoreData.then(function(store_data) {
    Stream = client.createStream(command_list);
    //recording = false;
//(........)
);

//Other function
```

Here is the solution to stream with BinaryJS with Chrome an Mozilla. Thanks to @jib and @Kaiido

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what calls the `success` function, it's difficult to say exactly, but I am fairly sure you want your `client.on('open')` listener to be contingent on the success function running.

I don't know how it will affect the rest of the omitted code, but I would only connect the `BinaryClient` when the success function has run and you are sure you have `store_data` defined.

```
function success() {
  var client = new BinaryClient('ws://localhost:9001');
  var context = null;
  var store_data  = null;

  // do the original success code here

  // now create that listener.
  client.on('open', function() {
    // do original code here
  });
}

// you probably have a line of code that looks like this
navigator.getUserMedia({}, success);
```

Moving all of your code into the success function may work, but it won't be elegant. Once you've got the flow working, I would suggest refactoring the code, by splitting each logical bit up into its own function.

Comment: `sucess` is called if the browser is compatible with `getusermedia`

Comment: Can you add the code which is responsible for calling it?

Comment: Ok, I added some code to the example to show you how that pattern could work. The main point is, you can't connect your BinaryClient until you're sure that `success` has been run (because it depends on the data in that function). To ensure that it doesn't connect before `success`, you must connect it during `success`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's a race. Your code must wait until getUserMedia succeeds ***and*** `open` is fired.

Promises are a great way to solve this:

```
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

(Use the above polyfill to access modern `getUserMedia` in all supported browsers.)

```
var client = new BinaryClient('ws://localhost:9001');
var context = null;
var store_data  = null;
//(.....)

var haveStoreData = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
  .then(function(stream) {
    audioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    context = new audioContext();
    audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    var bufferSize = 2048;
    return context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
  });

//(....)
client.on('open', function() {
  console.log("opened");

  haveStoreData.then(function(store_data) {
    console.log("createStream");
    Stream = client.createStream(command_list);
    var recording = false;

    window.startRecording = function() {
      document.getElementById("startbutton").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("stopbutton").disabled = false;

      recording = true;
      window.Stream.resume();
    };

    window.stopRecording = function() {
      document.getElementById("startbutton").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("stopbutton").disabled = true;

      recording = false;
      //window.Stream.end();
      window.Stream.pause();
    };

    store_data.onaudioprocess = function(e){
      if(!recording) return;
      console.log ('recording');
      var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
      window.Stream.write(convertoFloat32ToInt16(left));
    };
    //(..events generated from server..)
  })
  .catch(function(e) { console.error(e); });
});
```

This will give users time to choose "Allow" in the mic permission prompt (Unlike Chrome, Firefox asks the user for permission every time, unless they choose "Always Allow").

Comment: this solution give me this error:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: startRecording is not defined`, when I click in the button

Comment: and this error to: `TypeError: Failed to execute 'connect' on 'AudioNode': `

Comment: I think the problem is I am not connecting the audio node properly. @jib

Comment: Right, I merely took a saw to your example, to explain the general idea. You probably want to refactor this to ghost any recording buttons until the user has given mic permission, so they don't click them in the wrong order.

Comment: I already solved the problem. I will put the solution. Thanks for everything @jib